# tasseo authentication fails

Tags: cross-browser, graphite

I was wondering if anyone uses [Tasseo](https://github.com/obfuscurity/tasseo#readme) for their Graphite dashboards. I'm having some problems I dont quite get. Basically, Tasseo polls Graphite server for stats - if you have authentication enabled (http base auth) on your Graphite server then you must export `GRAPHITE_URL` and `GRAPHITE_AUTH` environment variables to the environment in which tasseo is running ie. if you run tasseo as runit service then your run script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                        

exec 2>&1                                                                        
export GRAPHITE_URL="https://graphite-url"                                      
export GRAPHITE_AUTH="user:password"                                
cd /app                                                                          
exec chpst -u tasseo bundle exec rackup -o 127.0.0.1 -p 5000 -s thin
```

What I noticed though is that IF I DONT authenticate to the Graphite in the SAME browser in which I'm running Tasseo in another tab (by running I literally mean running as Tasseo is just a sinatra app fully built in javascript ie it's running in your browser), then I'm NOT able to display ANY graphs. As soon as I authenticate against Graphite in the same browser all works fine.
Tasseo is using CORS ie. it's polling Graphite from within JavaScript so it might do something with it.

The most annoying thing is that I have to do this every time I restart tasseo app server :-( So when I restart tasseo I have to reload Graphite page - I assume so that is re-authenticates ?
Also I noticed that even though when I reload the Graphite tab, Tasseo works for a while and then after some time (dont have exact measures) it stops working - in Chrome's development console I can see that the `OPTIONS` requests to Graphite are failing - so the `GET` requests must too.
Anyone ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Just If anyone comes across this problem when setting up Tasseo then make sure if you're using Self Signed Certificate on Graphite server, then they MUST BE trusted by the browser which is running Tasseo's CORS java script. Otherwise you'll be noticing what is described above - once you set those self signed certificates as TRUSTED, everything wil work like a charm!